# how to addClass using $(function() { $('

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

here is what i have done so far:

//delcare html:

```
<div class="success" id="divStatus" style="display:none;" ><a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>
```

asp.net code behind:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "_key"+this.UniqueID, "$(function() { $('#divStatus').html('" + msg + "').show().fadeIn(9000).fadeOut(9000); });", true);
```

//css class:

```
.success
    {  
        display:block;  
        color: #4F8A10;
        background-color: #DFF2BF;
    }
```

there is only logical explanation i think of is that, there is no css class(.success) in the >> #divStatus in $function .... is defined?

**updated end**

i am trying to add an class to the below selector but not sure if this is the right way of doing, any help?

here is what i tried doing but i don't see the the class is added and no action ( expect to see some colours)

```
"$(function() { $('#divStatus').addClass('success').html(.........
```

here is the full code i am doing in asp.net in code-behind.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "_key"+this.UniqueID, "$(function() { $('#divStatus').html('" + msg + "').show().fadeIn(9000).fadeOut(9000); });", true);
```

Comment: `.show().fadeIn(9000).fadeOut(9000)` that's not gonna work like you think it is (ie: chaining the calls does not make `fadeOut` wait for `fadeIn` to finish).

Comment: it would be better to help if u add some detailed code in jsfiddle or jsbin....

Comment: i have updated my question, i am doing this from asp.net code-behind and i know it will work from plain html page.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for

**HTML**

```
<div id="divStatus"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#divStatus{
    display: none;
}

.success{
    color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#divStatus')
        .html('hello')
        .show('fade', 2000, function(){
            $(this).addClass('success');
        })
        .hide('fade', 2000);
});
```

an alternative to this could be

```
$(function() {
    $('#divStatus')
        .html('hello')
        .show('highlight', 2000, function(){
            $(this).addClass('success');
        });
});
```

Comment: i have updated my question, i am doing this from asp.net code-behind and i know it will work from plain html page.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to provide more information.  The addClass works basically just like you have.  Here is a fiddle to display the change you want on a button click:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/6mSXP/

Example: `$('#status').html('it worked').addClass('success');`

Comment: i have updated my question, i am doing this from asp.net code-behind and i know it will work from plain html page.

Comment: Is the registerclientscriptblock being called in a post back?

Comment: i have this `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock...` code in the event when the user clicks on the button i display that div

Comment: answer to your question , yes it being called

Comment: I think you should create a plain old javascript function: `function showConfirm(msg)` and then call that in your post back.. That way you can put an alert in there and see if it is actually being called.